# Force project to always build using VS2012/VC11 when using MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, c++-cli

**Note**: This is related to the *well known* VS2010/VS2012 problem of, under certain circumstances, having to specify `/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0` when using MSBuild to build C++/CLI applications.

Problem: When building my VS2012 C++/CLI application using the MSBuild task referring to a C++/CLI project file I need to add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0` to the MSBuild command line, otherwise I get this error:

```
error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
```

This only shows up when building on machines with both VS2010 and VS2012 installed, and even from a `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012` or after calling `%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat` myself.

Obviously I know the workaround already, but I would like to get rid of the requirement of specifiying *the same additional command-line argument all the time*.

Some details: I have a .proj file that sets up the MSBuild task for building the C++/CLI application. Here's the meat of it (let's call it `Foo.proj`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>

    <CxxProjects
      Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\**\*.vcxproj"
    />

  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(CxxProjects)
             Properties="VisualStudioVersion=11.0"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The above is not complete, it's just for illustration. The problem is that setting the property VisualStudioVersion for the MSBuild task as above doesn't help. I still get the same MSB8008 error. Unless ... yeah, using `MSBuild Foo.proj /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0`.

Is it possible to fix this somehow - am I missing something here? I could even go for editing the individual .vcxproj files themselves if I only knew how (I have tried already).

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/08/21/visual-studio-project-compatibility-and-visualstudioversion/ I suggest you use the AdditionalProperties tricks it links to here: http://sedodream.com/2009/04/29/MSBuildPropertiesAndAdditionalPropertiesKnownMetadata.aspx

Comment: I actually read that blog post but never got around to try AdditionalProperties. Need to give it a shot perhaps.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Post that as a reply and I'll award you the bounty. Read my own answer to the question for a rationale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here goes. The below is the *actual* minimal reproduction case - the one in my question actually worked. I guess I was switching back and forth between so many different minor changes that I ended up posting without actually testing that exact code. Sorry for that.

The culprit was assuming that `VisualStudioVersion` was not set initially unless I did it myself - at least not that early in the build process. For me it's pretty unintuitive that MSBuild depends on Visual Studio, and not only the other way around.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--
      The below causes the problem - VisualStudioVersion already
      have a 'default' value of 10.0 at this point and therefore
      is never set to 11.0
    -->
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' != ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <CxxProjects
      Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\**\*.vcxproj"
    />

  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(CxxProjects)
             Properties="VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

What never worked for me though was to set either `VisualStudioVersion` or `PlatformToolset` (yes, unconditionally this time) directly in the .vcxproj files - that seems to be too late in the build process, at least when building in this particular way.

Another thing that confused me was that even when *explicitly* setting up the build environment for VS2012 the `VisualStudioVersion` property defaults to VS2010.

Thanks to those that replied. What actually triggered me to find out the problems was the comment on my original question about using `<AdditionalProperties>`. I tried that and 'accidentally' hardcoded `11.0` instead of using `$(VisualStudioVersion)` - which lead me to get it working for my other cases as well by unconditionally setting `VisualStudioVersion`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion>11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Because of this I'll award the bounty to that commenter if he posts his suggestion as a reply instead of a comment. Otherwise I'll just let automatic awarding take place.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which level you want to fix it.

In Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets there is an import statement you can use:

`<Import Condition="'$(_ToolsetFound)' == 'true' and Exists('$(_PlatformFolder)ImportAfter')" Project="$(_PlatformFolder)ImportAfter\*.targets"/>`

which imports all *.targets files from a specific Platform-dependent ImportAfter folder. You can define the simplest file which sets any Properties on a global level (for all .vcpproj files)

> Edit1
>   This is the content of such file, you can name it any way you want, just ensure it matches the above wildcard `*.targets.` You has to figure out the correct path for file (find what's the path in `$(_PlatformFolder)` property

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup><VisualStudioVersion>11.0</VisualStudioVersion></PropertyGroup>
</Project>`

> /Edit1

Or you can use this Import from Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets

`<Import Condition=" '$(ForceImportAfterCppTargets)' != '' and exists('$(ForceImportAfterCppTargets)')" Project="$(ForceImportAfterCppTargets)"/>`

just declare `$(ForceImportAfterCppTargets)` property which points to a single specific file which will override it for every platform.

> Edit2
>   This approach is better if you want to affect only your build script - you have to do the same (put a file like in edit1) and pass the path to the file via 
>   `$(ForceImportAfterCppTargets)` property. Your build script will have something like this:

`<MSBuild Projects="@(CxxProjects) Properties="ForceImportAfterCppTargets=path_to_my_targets"/>`

> /Edit2

Or you can create corresponding environment variable - [MSBuild emits Properties from  Environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Hope this helps.

PS: if you can produce a msbuild log with `/verbosity:diag` that may help you and us a lot - mush easier to see the full and very detailed log. Two sets of logs - one with successful build results and one with failed will help even more

Comment: Where should I put the above statements, exactly? As for the environment variable I was aware of that, but unfortunately that wasn't was I was looking for.

Comment: Umm, I need to make a working example to play a bit with the set up. I'm not a VC++ dev so not sure about exact changes.
Regarding 1st part - you can make a file let's say MyImportAfter.targets
with a specific override (see edit1).
Put it in the folder on your machine\build server and it will affect all your builds. literally every one on that machine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I've found the problem already and will post the solution ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, specific to the VS2012 with VS2010 combination, is described with details here: [Visual Studio project compatibility and VisualStudioVersion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/08/21/visual-studio-project-compatibility-and-visualstudioversion/)

> If you build a web project from the command line (not the developer
>   prompt) then the value for VisualStudioVersion used will be 10.0. That
>   is an artifact of the properties which I showed above. In this case
>   you should pass this in as an MSBuild property. For example
>
> `msbuild.exe MyAwesomeWeb.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0`
>
> In this
>   case I’m passing in the property explicitly. This will always override
>   any other mechanism to determine the value for VisualStudioVersion. If
>   you are using the MSBuild task in a build script, then you can specify
>   the property either in the Properties attribute or the
>   AdditionalProperties attribute.

The post has a link to another post here: [MSBuild: Properties and AdditionalProperties Known Metadata](http://sedodream.com/2009/04/29/MSBuildPropertiesAndAdditionalPropertiesKnownMetadata.aspx). This article explains this:

> The difference is that if you specify properties using the Properties
>   metadata then any properties defined using the Properties attribute on
>   the MSBuild Task will be ignored. In contrast to that if you use the
>   AdditionalProperties metadata then both values will be used, with a
>   preference going to the AdditionalProperties values.

So one solution is to use the [AdditionalProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) metadata that allow to define Properties late in the msbuild process, something like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <CxxProjects Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\**\*.vcxproj">
        <AdditionalProperties>VisualStudioVersion=11.0</AdditionalProperties>
    </CxxProjects>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(CxxProjects) />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: As I say in [my own reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38237660/81588) my problem was slightly different but your comment triggered me finding the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a particular toolset within the project file by adding the following tag to a property group:

```
<PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
```

You shouldn't need any external parameters at all with this.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Still the same MSB8008 error. Already tried something similar.

Comment: Unfortunate. I've got a similar situation with three versions of Visual Studio installed (at the moment) and it's been working fine for me.

Comment: Incidentally, I've also got these environment variables defined:   VS110COMNTOOLS, VS120COMNTOOLS, VS140COMNTOOLS

Comment: Me too, as well as VS100COMNTOOLS. Do you actually have VS2010 installed (I believe that's where the problem is)?

Comment: Don't have VS2010 installed, sorry. It's conceivable that you've got an old version of MSBuild that's somehow unable to pick up other toolset versions

Comment: The problem is specific to VS2010+VS2012 in combination